# Make TabNavigator same for all the drawer navigator pages React Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I just need an extra tip regarding to drawer navigator and tab navigator.

What i am doing is wrapping Tab Navigator in Stack Navigator and then Stack Navigator into Drawer Navigator and everything is working fine for my Home screen layout.

in my drawer there is only menu "HOME" and after login that one is the landing page. and at "HOME" screen i have the Tab Navigator which is working perfect.

What i want to do is using the same Tab Navigator for all my Drawer Navigator menus. which currently applied in the HOME menu only.

And when i click on any menu in drawer navigation it should navigate to that page with the return icon on the top header like stack navigator. and clicking on the back button it should come back to home page tab menu.

> Screens related to this are,
>
> Home Screen With Tab Navigator

[image]

> Drawer navigator

[image]

> After click the product menu its showing like this

[image]

> What i want it to look like this with Tab Navigator and back button on top

[image]

Any Help please?

Comment: hmmm interesting!  well in your use case!  what you can do is just add the product Detail component in your Tab Navigator as a screen! but that would be very awkward don't you think? it will be also showing a tab in bottom saying Product Detail!.

Comment: Yeah Rizwan atta it would be awkward.  i already do it by adding product detail button in my home screen as you can see in pic, which is doing the same thing as i really want. but i want it using drawer navigator.